# How to add script editor and media and content sections in sharepoint page?

Tags: iframe, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, power-automate

I believe I am using Sharepoint online. If not how to verify if its Sharepoint classic or online?
In the SharePoint ,I don't find 'script editor' or 'media and content' sections in the editor web elements of the page. How do I add them?.

I tried logging into SharePoint once again but I don't see these web elements.
Please check soon and help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The interface for adding web parts will be different. The elements you are describing are from the classic interface and will not be available in the Modern Team Site.

With a Classic Team site you will see a ribbon which will include actions like inserting a web part.

[image]

With a Modern Team site you will get a web parts dialog in the centre of the page.

[image]

I have seen custom alternatives for the modern interface, like the SPFX React Script editor:
https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-script-editor

Answer (score 0):

Check below Microsoft official documentation to figure out if you are using classic experience or modern experience in SharePoint online:

[SharePoint classic and modern experiences](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sharepoint-classic-and-modern-experiences-5725c103-505d-4a6e-9350-300d3ec7d73f)

Content Editor and Script Editor are classic experience web parts in SharePoint. If you are using SharePoint online modern experience, those will not be visible on SharePoint pages while adding web parts.

For SharePoint online modern experience, you have to use the custom script editor web part developed using SPFx by community memebers.

You can find it at: [Script editor web part for modern pages built in React](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-script-editor)

Check below Microsoft official documentation related to deploying SPFx web parts in SharePoint online: [Deploy your client-side web part to a SharePoint page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/serve-your-web-part-in-a-sharepoint-page)